# Create smoother animation on carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, carousel

I'm in the process of making a carousel-based Tumblr theme [HERE](http://roseannebarr.tumblr.com) but I'm very disappointed with the animation. Is there anything I can add to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2
/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/chili-1.7.pack.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle
/jquery.cycle.all.2.72.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com  
/jquery.easing.1.1.1.js">      
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.fn.cycle.defaults.timeout = 6000;

$('#s7').cycle({ 
fx:    'scrollRight', 
speed: 'fast',
timeout: 0,
easeIn:  'bounceout', 
easeOut: 'backin', 
next:   '#next2', 
prev:   '#prev2'
});

function onBefore() {
$('#output').html("Scrolling image:<br>" + this.src);
//window.console.log(  $(this).parent().children().index(this) );
}
function onAfter() {
$('#output').html("Scroll complete for:<br>" + this.src)
    .append('<h3>' + this.alt + '</h3>');
}
</script>
```

To make the animation of the carousel smoother?

Comment: looks smooth enough on me (Chrome)

Comment: It looks good in Chrome (sort of) but it's choppy in Firefox. I wish I could make it (this is going to sound stupid) iPhone looking smooth.

Comment: I think making the speed slower (`speed: 'slow'` even) will help, both easing transitions don't seem well suited to a fast speed IMO.

Comment: For animations, Nitro (Safari) is crazy fast, V8 (Chrome) is quite good. JägerMonkey (FF4) is ok, but not as good. TraceMonkey (FF 3.6) is pretty poor. Nothing much you can do about it.

Comment: You need to change your cycle options, mate.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change up your options, mate.**

```
$('#s7').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollRight',
    speed: 1000,
    timeout: 0,
    next: '#next2',
    prev: '#prev2',
    easing: 'easeinout'
});
```

Comment: Updated options to make it more smooth.

Comment: Sweet! I changed it to 500 and now it's perfect. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a good experience with defining my images as background images in CSS, rather than using actual  tags in HTML. This greatly increased the smoothness of scrolling using a Bootstrap carousel and Chrome. The markup / CSS for this would be something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="my-image">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#my-image {
  background:url("image.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The smoothness (or lack thereof) of an animation like this depends a lot on the browser in use, as well as the computer being used (slower computer = more stilted animation).

You might try using a more [CSS3](http://blog.joelambert.co.uk/2011/05/05/flux-slider-css3-animation-based-image-transitions/) based approach (i.e. less reliant on JS), but that would be limited to modern browsers (in this case webkit only).

Comment: "...(in this case webkit only)." False, amigo.  Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions. Opera: http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto23/css/transitions

Comment: @Levi You're absolutely correct mate, my _in this case_ was in reference to my linked example, which only uses -webkit- transitions/animations.

Comment: Also it might be a badly written jQuery plugin. Consider writing your own if you only want a simple carousel, or use another. I've used [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) before and it seems [pretty good](http://www.jwspeaker.com).

Comment: I would love to but the thing is with Tumblr I had to find a specific carousel that would list each post as a different slide and it's very uncommon when I find one.